# Show how many characters remaining in a HTML text box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea

This is my code:

```
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, 160);
        field.blur();
        field.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
}
```

How can I display how many characters are remaining from a certain text box with a limit of 160?

Comment: Whats the question? Does that code not work? And if it doesn't, what does it do instead of what you expect?

Comment: @AlexWayne it only sets up the max limit of the text area which is 306. My Code doesn't work, and i need to set the limit to 160 only.

Comment: What server technology are you using? You should also consider server-side length validation, otherwise your approach can be bypassed if the user has JavaScript turned off in their browser.

Comment: If you want a pure javascript solution and not jQuery check out my answer, i have a demo attached for you.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[Dynamic HTML element function](https://jsfiddle.net/dilipsassy/udv521cL/22/)The code in [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=733) with a little bit of modification and simplification:

```
<input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="10" id="counter">
<textarea onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',10);" id="message">
</textarea>
<script>
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit)
{
 var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
 if ( field.value.length > maxlimit ) {
  field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
  return false;
 } else {
  countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
 }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

tip:

When merging the codes with your page, make sure the HTML elements(`textarea`, `input`) are loaded first before the scripts (Javascript functions)

Comment: The keypress event is only fired when a key normally produces a character value. So you won't be able to catch backspace or paste actions.

I'd recommend to use the input event instead -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: consider using something like this to catch content changes as keyup won't handle all cases: #("message").bind('input propertychange', function () {textCounter(this,'counter',10);})

Answer (score 40):

You can bind key press event with your input box and returning `false` if characters are more than 160 will solve the problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r34gM/1/).

JavaScript:

```js
$('textarea').keypress(function(){

    if(this.value.length > 160){
        return false;
    }

    $("#remainingC").html("Remaining characters : " + (160 - this.value.length));
});​
```

HTML

```html
<textarea></textarea>​
<span id='remainingC'></span>
```

Comment: I need the number of the remaining characters.

Comment: @Shusl that is HTML i need it in C#

Comment: @ChristineS But your question is related to JavaScript and textarea.

Comment: @Shusl yes but I'm doing it in C#

Comment: @ChristineS Sorry I don't have any idea how to use JS and HTML in C#

Comment: @Shusl this is the site where i copy the code i'm having a problem with [CharactersRemainingCode](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=733)

Comment: Its not working as expected when I copy/paste the content

Comment: It fails to update the textarea after it reaches the limit.

Comment: Nice and easy solution @Anoop, however I made some small adaptions: http://jsfiddle.net/r34gM/203/ ... I use keyup rather than keypress (to trap BACKSPACE) and I tried to generalize the approach a bit more. Of course the markup needs to be set correctly (span element after the textarea).

Comment: @konrad_pe Thanks! You should post that as a standalone answer, it's the best on this page right now. Although I don't know about including `.next()` for the display count field.

Comment: awesome, concise solution !!

Answer (score 9):

Included below is a simple working JS/HTML implementation which updates the remaining characters properly when the input has been deleted.

Bootstrap and JQuery are required for the layout and functionality to match. (*Tested on JQuery 2.1.1 as per the included code snippet*).

Make sure you include the JS code such that it is loaded after the HTML. Message me if you have any questions.

#### Le Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var len = 0;
  var maxchar = 200;

  $( '#my-input' ).keyup(function(){
    len = this.value.length
    if(len > maxchar){
        return false;
    }
    else if (len > 0) {
        $( "#remainingC" ).html( "Remaining characters: " +( maxchar - len ) );
    }
    else {
        $( "#remainingC" ).html( "Remaining characters: " +( maxchar ) );
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label>Textarea</label>
    <textarea placeholder="Enter the textarea input here.. (limited to 200 characters)" rows="3" class="form-control" name="my-name" id="my-input" maxlength="200"></textarea><span id='remainingC'></span>
  </div>
</div> <!--row-->
```

Comment: I tried this example, and it stops allowing input at "Remaining characters: 6".  Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

Just register an Eventhandler on `keydown` events and check the length of the input field on that function and write it into a separate element.

See the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/AvH3Q/)**.

```
var maxchar = 160;
var i = document.getElementById("textinput");
var c = document.getElementById("count");
c.innerHTML = maxchar;

i.addEventListener("keydown",count);

function count(e){
    var len =  i.value.length;
    if (len >= maxchar){
       e.preventDefault();
    } else{
       c.innerHTML = maxchar - len-1;   
    }
}
​
```

You should check the length on your server too, because Javascript might be disabled or the user wants to do something nasty on purpose.

Comment: I've tried it and it works well in JSfiddle. but when i combine it with my page it just wont show the Remaining Characters :( and by the way my language is C#

Comment: @Christine change the 306 in  `onblur="textCounter(this,this.form.counter,306);"` to 160. and change the 160 in `field.value.substring(0, 160);` back to `maxlimit`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="8" cols="50" maxlength="100" ></textarea>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var max = 1000;
        $('#feedback').html(max + 'characters remaining');

        $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
            var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
            var text_remaining = max - text_length;

            $('#feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach, which splits the problem into two parts:

- Using jQuery, it shows a decrementing counter below the `textarea`, which turns red when it hits zero but still allows the user to type.
- I use a separate string length validator (server and client-side) to actually prevent submission of the form if the number of chatacters in the `textarea` is greater than 160.

My `textarea` has an id of `Message`, and the `span` in which I display the number of remaining characters has an id of `counter`. The css class of `error` gets applied when the number of remaining characters hits zero.

```
var charactersAllowed = 160;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Message').keyup(function () {
        var left = charactersAllowed - $(this).val().length;
        if (left < 0) {
            $('#counter').addClass('error');
            left = 0;
        }
        else {
            $('#counter').removeClass('error');
        }
        $('#counter').text('Characters left: ' + left);
    });
});
```

Comment: User want answer in javascript not in jquery

Comment: @ChristineS I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RichardEv this is the site where i copy the code i'm having a problem with [CharactersRemainingCode](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=733)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for instance:

working code in **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/7ktFX/)**

For textArea, use this:

```
<textarea id="txtBox"></textarea>
...
...
```

For textBox, use this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox"/>
<br>
<input type="text" id="counterBox"/>
<script>
 var txtBoxRef = document.querySelector("#txtBox");
 var counterRef = document.querySelector("#counterBox");
 txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
  var remLength = 0;
  remLength = 160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
  if(remLength < 0)
   {
    txtBoxRef.value = txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 160);
    return false;
   }
  counterRef.value = remLength + " characters remaining...";
 },true);
</script>
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: @Crystal Paladin this is the site where i copy the code i'm having a problem with [CharactersRemainingCode](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=733)

Comment: @vaahost how did you do it? I can't combine it with my page.

Comment: @ChristineS i have changed little code in that so it got worked for me

Comment: @ChristineS may I have a little peek at the code u're trying to combine this with?

Comment: @CrystalPaladin this is where i copy the whole codes [CharactersRemainingCode](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=733)

Answer (score 0):

try this code in here...this is done using javascript onKeyUp() function...

```
<script>
function toCount(entrance,exit,text,characters) {  
var entranceObj=document.getElementById(entrance);  
var exitObj=document.getElementById(exit);  
var length=characters - entranceObj.value.length;  
if(length <= 0) {  
length=0;  
text='<span class="disable"> '+text+' <\/span>';  
entranceObj.value=entranceObj.value.substr(0,characters);  
}  
exitObj.innerHTML = text.replace("{CHAR}",length);  
}
</script>
```

[textarea counter demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4epdC/)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like that and the solution I gave with the help of jquery is this:

```
<textarea class="textlimited" data-textcounterid="counter1" maxlength="30">text</textarea>
<span class='textcounter' id="counter1"></span>
```

With this script:

```
// the selector below will catch the keyup events of elements decorated with class textlimited and have a maxlength
$('.textlimited[maxlength]').keyup(function(){
     //get the fields limit
    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");

    // check if the limit is passed
    if(this.value.length > maxLength){
        return false;
    }

    // find the counter element by the id specified in the source input element
    var counterElement = $(".textcounter#" + $(this).data("textcounterid"));
    // update counter 's text
    counterElement.html((maxLength - this.value.length) + " chars left");
});
```

Α live demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cnom/ou1r9a6k/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <form>
  <textarea id='text' maxlength='10'></textarea>
  <div id='msg'>10 characters left</div>
  <div id='lastChar'></div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function charCount() {
  var textEntered = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  var counter = (10-(textEntered.length));
  msg.textContent = counter+' characters left';
}

var el = document.getElementById('text');
el.addEventListener('keyup',charCount,false);
```