# How to show number of characters typed in textarea in a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the number of characters typed into a textarea to put into one textbox, and the number of words from the textarea to put in the other, as I press Enter.

```
<textarea name="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea><br>

<input name="Text1" type="text" />Characters
<input name="Text1" type="text" />Words
```

Comment: Just take `.value.length`? What part of the task do you have problems with?

Comment: So what have you tried? Is something not working? SO Is not a coding service, we're not going to write this for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show how many characters remaining in a HTML text box using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742595/show-how-many-characters-remaining-in-a-html-text-box-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [textarea character limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit)

Comment: I do not need a service. I tried looking for similar solutions but I couldn't find. Maybe I did not search well enough; however, I just am in need of someone to tell me how I should start out with the function.
All I found was how to show the amount of characters remaining, as it shows underneath.

Comment: Okay thank you @MelanciaUK. I guess that was what I was looking for. Sorry for enraging recent posters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add an event listener which listens for the `keyup` (or `keydown`) event on the textarea.

Once you have that, you would need to check that the `keyCode` matches the return key (**13**).

After that, its a simple case of counting the `length` of the textarea value and splitting its value via the spaces in order to count the words.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var characters = this.value.length;
    var words = this.value.split(' ').length;
    document.getElementById('characters').value = characters;
    document.getElementById('words').value = words;
    
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea name="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" id="textarea"></textarea><br>

<input name="Text1" type="text" id="characters"/>Characters
<input name="Text1" type="text" id="words" />Words
```